# Replace Kendogrid command buttons with only icons

Tags: angularjs, kendo-grid

I have edit and delete buttons in my kendogrid, and I just want to put some different icons for them.
I tried a few approaches like:

```
command:
          [
            { name: 'edit', text: { edit: ' ', update: ' ', cancel: '' } },
            { name: 'destroy', text: ' ' , template: '<a href=""><span class="delete_icon"></span></a>' }
          ]


 .k-grid-edit {
    background-color: transparent !important;
    border: medium none !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
    min-width: 0 !important;
}
```

In this case, I can see my new icon for the delete button.
But now how to change icons for edit, update and cancel buttons?

I am not able to use a template for the edit button. Why is that not possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51258733/1179865) to your other question applies here too. You could use a font awesome icon for the edit and delete buttons and still bind to the built in functions.

```
{"command": [
    {
      "text": "Edit",
      "template": "<a role='button' class='k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-edit'><span class='far fa-edit'></span></a>"
    },
    {
      "text": "Delete",
      "template": "<a role='button' class='k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-delete'><span class='far fa-trash-alt'></span></a>"
    }
  ]
}
```

As I mentioned in my last answer, the magic that binds the button to the built in function is in the classes `k-grid-delete` and `k-grid-edit`

Here's an [example that uses custom icons](https://dojo.telerik.com/abEGAjey/4)